# "Descontextualizado" é uma péssima tradução para off-topic

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução, localização, razões-fechamento

O Gabe disse isto aqui no bate-papo:

[image: odeio "descontextualização" == "off-topic"]

Ele tem toda a razão! E também tem as ferramentas para consertar isso, então vamos ajudar sugerindo algumas opções.

**Poste a sua sugestão como resposta!** Se tiver mais de uma sugestão, poste-as como respostas separadas, para que possam ter votação independente.

Comment: “Descontextualizado” só é um problema se houver outro sentido que venha a confundir o leitor.

Comment: Talvez, mas soa tão feio! Sem falar no erro de concordância em *fechada como descontextualizado...*

Comment: Pelo jeito há umas traduções automáticas rolando no SO. Isso vai contra o sentido de se ter um site em português... :(

Comment: Pelo que vi os tradutores eram humanos, mas tiveram bastante dificuldade com material que receberam "picado", como trechos para serem interpolados em mensagens da interface.

Comment: Faz sentido, uma pena de qq forma.

Comment: Sem dúvida. Eu sempre achei que deveria haver algum tipo de ferramenta de tradução comunitária, ainda antes do site entrar no ar em beta privado.

Comment: Poste em Portugal é isto http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-x1oTCrNM1BY/T3pFHUiLZSI/AAAAAAAAAMc/wryVEqJuIVk/s1600/VJUDEU_poste.jpg

Answer (score 15):

### Off-topic

Pra falar a verdade eu acho que "Off-topic" seria o melhor termo a utilizar, em todos os fóruns e sistemas de comentários esse termo é utilizado. A tradução ao pé da letra seria "fora do assunto".

No próprio [wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-topic) diz:

> **Off Topic**, **off-topic** (ou abreviado para **OT**, ou até mesmo a expressão "**em off**") é um termo em inglês bastante comum no internetês que traduzido seria "**fora do assunto**". É utilizado geralmente nos títulos de fóruns ou listas de discussão para indicar que o assunto do corpo da mensagem não tem a ver com o tema principal previamente proposto. É também muito comum que o termo seja colocado entre colchetes ([ e ]) assim: [OT] , [Off Topic] e [OFF]

É até utilizado comumente em nosso meio ([wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-topic)):

> O termo se tornou tão comum que certas vezes extrapola o mundo virtual e é usado no cotidiano de milhares de pessoas ao redor do mundo para indicar uma situação fora do contexto situado no momento. Por exemplo: numa roda de conversa onde o assunto no momento é "futebol", tolera-se trocar "mudando de assunto..." por "em off" ou "off-topic".

Apesar da sugestão para tradução, acharia interessante utilizar "Off-topic" mesmo.

Comment: Alterei a sugestão apresentada para a que eu acho melhor, assim não tem confusão

Comment: Pessoalmente, minha favorita. Acho que assim como "post", é um termo difundido o suficiente. Mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: @Gabe Acho que esses termos já estão bem difundidos, isso desde a época do orkut kkk, acho que a maioria já sabe o que é, principalmente programadores.

Comment: Editou? Devias ter criado uma nova resposta. Que os votos estão na antiga. Eu agora votava +1.

Answer (score 14):

### Fora de escopo

Ou seja, a pergunta exige respostas que vão além do que o site se propõe oferecer, portanto está **fora do escopo do site**. Isso é bem genérico, então funciona tanto para assuntos que são de fato *off-topic*, quanto para os motivos *off-topic* customizados que deveremos ter no futuro.

Comment: Isso. Apenas isso e nada mais do que isso.

Comment: Acho estranho que "fora de escopo" seja considerado melhor que "fora do assunto" ou "fora do tema". É só considerar o original em Inglês: a expressão "out of scope" não é utilizada necessariamente nas mesmas situações que "off-topic".

Comment: Não dá pra traduzir diretamente do inglês. Para mim, escopo em português tem um uso diferente. Mas ainda prefiro *off-topic* mesmo... @rsenna

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu já acho que escopo e "scope" tem significados muito próximos, quase idênticos. De qualquer forma é uma discussão subjetiva, e provavelmente concordamos que "descontextualizado" é a pior alternativa.

Comment: @rsenna Tem mais uma coisa: sou a favor de uma tradução que não use os termos "tema" ou "assunto", pois a interface de fechamento de pesquisa permite colocar motivos customizados embaixo de off-topic (por exemplo, no site em inglês há opções para perguntas de recomendação e para perguntas que não dão informações suficientes para reproduzir o problema).

Comment: nhaca tuga, nhaca tuga. Tem de fugir sempre para o pt_BR é inevitável.

Comment: Escopo vem de scope? Que mania de criar palavras novas que vocês têm...

Answer (score 5):

### Fora do contexto

Estou pondo alternativas para que as pessoas possam dar feedback em separado.

Comment: (des.con.tex.tu:a.li.za.ção) 1. Ação ou resultado de descontextualizar, de retirar do contexto

Answer (score 3):

**Fora do âmbito**

Âmbito em alternativa à palavra *Escopo* que não é utilizada em Portugal.

Comment: +1, escopo e claramente PT-BR, a alternativa comum as linguas lusofonas seria ambito.

Comment: os tugas em acordo :D

Answer (score 1):

### Fora do tema

Tradução alternativa para off-topic

Answer (score 1):

## Fora de tópico

Felizmente, ou infelizmente, foi a primeira coisa que pensei quando vi a palavra *off-topic*.

Answer (score 0):

### Descontextualizado

Não sei como ninguém colocou esta.

Answer (score -1):

### Fora do assunto

Mais uma alternativa.

Answer (score -2):

### Incompatível

(com os temas e tipos de pergunta aceitos no site)